# Uniform distribution - a simple question

Tags: probability, self-study, uniform-distribution

I know this is a really simple one, but for some reason I see various ways and I'm not sure which one should I follow.

So - I have $Y_1,...Y_n \sim U(1,3)$ and I want to know $P(y<c)$.

The answer that I have for this (and it's different from how I see in Wiki) is:
$c+\int_1^c 0.5\,dy $

Is this the correct way?
If so, what's the logic behind it?

Comment: Put $c = 1$ and your $P(x < c)$ becomes 1, but 1 is the lower limit of your distribution, so the formula is quite wrong. Even more compelling: for any $c>1$ the formula yields answers greater than 1, which can not be right for a probability. If you know mathematics up to integration, this really should not be difficult. (As @Peter Flom points out, no calculus is needed any way.)

Comment: How did you get that answer?

Comment: this is the answer on a test copy I have from past student

Comment: It's *nonsense*. By the way, please add the `self-study` tag.

Comment: What is $y$ and what is its connection with the $Y_i$? Could it be their average? Their maximum? Their minimum?  That, I believe, is the basis of @Glen_b's complaint.

Comment: The question as written doesn't explain what $y$ is intended to be as @whuber says, but if it's a random variable, then the integration with respect to it doesn't make sense. If it's not a random variable then the $P(y<c)$ doesn't make sense. In any case, it's not clear what interpretation of the question should give such an answer. Please check the question carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking an intuitive approach - you want the area under the curve between 1 and c. So, why would you *add* c to the integration?

But you don't need calculus here; Wikipedia has the [right answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29). It will give the same result as the integration without the extra c. The uniform distribution is just a rectangle, so you don't need calculus, just some very basic geometry.

Comment: Wikipedia has the right answer to what? How do you interpret this question?

Comment: I interpreted as the probability that a draw from a Uniform sample U(1,3) would be less than c.